# React Material UI Removing autofill background colour

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am looking for a solution to remove the background color of autofill selection. Every time that I use an autofill value the background color becomes another color.

[Current Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t73RO.png)

I know that it can be worked around using

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px white inset
```

but since I am using a transparent background I can't just cover it with a solid color and  couldn't find a solution that makes the background of autofill transparent instead.

[This is what I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioQA7.png)

Current Code,

```
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
    root: {
        margin: '2%',
        fontSize: '16px',
        padding: '2%',
        width: '50%',
        background: 'rgba(20, 20, 20, .7 )',
        borderRadius: '10px',
        outline: 'none',
        "&:focus":{
            color: "yellow",
        outlineColor: 'white',
        borderBottomColor: 'white',
        }
    },
    input: {
        color: 'white',
        "&::after": {
            borderBottom: "2px solid rgb(165, 51, 47)"
          },
          '& :-webkit-autofill': {
            '-webkit-text-fill-color': 'white',
            '-webkit-box-shadow': '0 0 0px 1000px #00000000 inset',
          },    
    },
}


function ClassNames(props) {
const { classes, children, className, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <TextField 
        className={clsx(classes.root, className)} {...other} 
        InputProps={{className: classes.input}}
    />
  );
}

ClassNames.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  className: PropTypes.string,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ClassNames);
```

Tried using #00000000 as recommended by one of the comments but it didn't do anything
[#00000000 and changed text-colour to white](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph4Ff.png)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow .Please add a code snippet. read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question.

Comment: Why don't you change `white` to `#00000000` if you need a transparent background ?

Comment: I tried that and added the current code I have at hand to the post, it didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 1):

Just add a delay to the browser animation:

```
      '& :-webkit-autofill': {
        transition-delay: 9999s
      },
```